# Firebase RT Database Query on field value hash equality

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Realtime Database with users and the email is stored in a child field, for example:

```
/users/00Vho6lTQke46IqpRv0D5dw6DXs2/email -> user@email.com
```

I want to query once and get a user based on the MD5 hash of the email address. For example, `MD5('user@email.com') -> 'b58c6f14d292556214bd64909bcdb118'`.

I don't have the email address of the user, I only have the MD5 hash. Is it possible to query using an MD5 function to transform the email field to MD5 and query on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to query using an MD5 function to transform the email field to MD5 and query on that?

No, unless you save the MD5 as a field inside the database. If you do that, you'll be able to query using the MD5. Your schema should look like this:

```
db
|
--- users
     |
     --- 00Vho6lTQke46IqpRv0D5dw6DXs2
           |
           --- email: "user@email.com"
           |
           --- md5: "b58c6f14d292556214bd64909bcdb118"
```

And the query should look like this:

```
val query = db.child("users").orderByChild("md5").equalTo("b58c6f14d292556214bd64909bcdb118");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I cannot change the data structure of the user there and add that md5 field for different reasons. And of course, looping through all users isn't scalable. I have decided to ask the provider to  change the source to include the actual email, since there is obviously no other solution than the one you provided.

Thanks anyways.